# Symfony2 + nginx serving pdf files?

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, nginx, response

I try show file pdf in controller Symfony2, my action is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/manual/pdf", name="helps_user_manual")
 */
public function userManualAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $file = $em->getRepository('AllusInventoryBundle:Files')->findOneByHashFile('4b2edce2ae98a2a9915d7a1f8cb482f5');

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'inline');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
    $response->headers->set('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $response->setContent(readfile($file->getAbsolutePath('pdf')));

    return $response;
}
```

And my configuration in nginx is:

```
http {
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

sendfile on;
#tcp_nopush on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout 65;
server_tokens off;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json  application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x

# enabled sites
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

}

In my development environment I'm using apache and the pdf is displayed successfully. But in my production environment shows me the following:

> %PDF-1.5 %µµµµ 1 0 obj <>>> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <>/XObject<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœµXÛn7} à£À\Éá¥ØNR8€UÛÃ‚-»*l©u”Ío÷:ÜµlIËá2U‹]™{öÌýÒœ<®·³ëµxýº9Y¯g×¿ÌoÄesºZ¯WWÍô¯ßæÍÇÙÝb9[/VË7oÄéÛ3q:š÷ @‹éíxBÑt^ È¬˜>ŒGJÜ¥Ë÷ãÑå‘˜\‰é‡ñè½™ÞÞ¼¢ƒ4Z˜ Áµïìžï.Î„h>&rgço…Ú"°°ZÚ ‚Ò«0€Åð!H_…¡yoe¬Â0<†ƒJ}XÃzil òÆH¬ÂpiŒQu ü:À’ê:~1J[Â/lJu üFÀ¨UlØ÷þÎÊB€Uhûñõ«l¥²-¿Ð2‘´Ê¡-¿Ñ2ÞIWÂ{±qZ†g196/W·ûÃ$ðÏßzÔý‹oq[Fˆüž......

Nginx not accepted the 'Content-Type', 'application / pdf', Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you're implementing something like [PDF.js in Symfony](https://github.com/nibsirahsieu/SalvaPdfJsBundle), this isn't a Symfony question. Just put your PDF files in the same place you put any other static asset like JS, CSS etc and make sure your server can handle those files.

Comment: My files pdf is in web/uploads/pdf, and my js, css, and img is in web/bundlename/css|js|img